# How to get one pixel of Image in Windows Store App (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, image, windows-store-apps, pixel

I am writing a game for Windows 8 in C#. I have an Image and I need to check the color of some given pixel. I know coordinates (x, y) of the pixel in Image, but I can not find any class that can do that. For example
`System.Drawing.Bitmap` has method `GetPixel`, which would be perfect for me, but I can not use this class in Windows Store apps.

Does anyone know how can I do it? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used it, but you could try the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) class. The project page states that the class has a `GetPixel` method.

If you want to implement this yourself (it is not trivial, and takes quite a few function calls), one way is to use `BitmapDecoder` to read the bitmap and [BitMapDecoder.GetPixelData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.getpixeldataasync%28v=win.10%29.aspx) to get a `PixelDataProvider`. From there you can get a byte buffer using [DetachPixelData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.pixeldataprovider.detachpixeldata%28v=win.10%29.aspx). The byte buffer is a one dimensional array in RGBA format. You'll have to map your x and y coordinates to this array.

Comment: That looks promising! I will try it out and say how did it work :)

Comment: @chuex I have also used WriteableBitmapEx, but what i want to do download the image and then change its color to different colors based on requirement. Can you add some sample code for it ?